# Equivalent of an edge side include in a universal React application

Tags: reactjs, universal, isomorphic-javascript, edge-side-includes

I have a universal React application. Within one of the pages I want to include some HTML from another server - [Edge side includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes) (ESI) have been mentioned, but this methodology doesn't seem to be compatible with Universal React applications, as:

1. we may not be able to recreate the functionality of an Edge side include client side, at least not without revealing the external URL to the browser. I guess we could create a proxy page on our server to do this, and load the html snippet via AJAX when doing this client side, but that still leaves us with the second issue...
2. Using an ESI means injecting non React DOM content in to the already (server side) rendered DOM of the React application when processing on CDN server. I am pretty sure this would make the data-react-checksum invalid and I can't think of a way to avoid this.

Is there an alternative, React-friendly, universal rendering approach that could be used?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet, still thinking about a few alternatives

Comment: I am in a similar situation., what solution worked for you .? can you please add that here.?